# Bizarrely unable to access elements in an ActionController::Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

Making an extension to an already-written rails project. In an erb file I have:

`<%= form_for @uploaded_planners[0], :url => method_path, :html => { 
   :multipart => true } do |form| %>
     <%= form.file_field :pic %>
     <%=form.submit 'Upload'%>
   <% end %>`

In the appropriate controller I have:

```
def create
  p params
  print "\n"
  testing = params[:uploaded_planner]
  print testing.class
  print "\n"
  print testing
  print "\n"
  print testing['@original_filename']
  print testing[:original_filename]
  print "\n"
end
```

and:

```
def plan
    @uploaded_planners = UploadedPlanner.all #there are two i inserted via rails console..
end
```

Output of those prints are

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"UxgdziS9PwY/SAaOMj4upXzSTf5brOT4R9x+paMNNlxehYwY34OT7hvdGJXwvK/cffPIjYOwdf1h+MndJh6LBg==", "uploaded_planner"=>{"pic"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f9b9b3bc5e8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/hc/67y08p7s3ws6rsjl5rlxk3f00000gn/T/RackMultipart20170801-25372-godqfg.xlsx>, @original_filename="AF_CSX_DISTRIBUTE_NUMBERS.xlsx", @content_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_planner[pic]\"; filename=\"AF_CSX_DISTRIBUTE_NUMBERS.xlsx\"\r\nContent-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Upload", "controller"=>"viacom", "action"=>"create"}

ActionController::Parameters

{"pic"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f9b9d529190 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/hc/67y08p7s3ws6rsjl5rlxk3f00000gn/T/RackMultipart20170801-25372-baavaj.xlsx>, @original_filename="AF_CSX_DISTRIBUTE_NUMBERS.xlsx", @content_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_planner[pic]\"; filename=\"AF_CSX_DISTRIBUTE_NUMBERS.xlsx\"\r\nContent-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet\r\n">}
```

The bottom two print statements are nil. My statements do not dig into the double-nested hash and retrieve the values I am trying to get. I tried every combination syntax-wise that I know of to try to get to those values out of the hash, but to no avail - every time I get nothing. I know the 'create' method in my controller is being invoked - it's how I am getting this print output - it's just I cannot get any value in the hash of "uploaded_planner" (aka can't index into the testing variable). I cannot figure out how to reference those members by any means, which sucks, as those are the members I really want to get to.

Here is the official ActionController doc:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-extract-21

It alleges that I can do:

```
params[:key]
```

And I can... the first time. But after that, the object that I have is still an ActionController::Parameters (as shown by my .class print statement) yet I cannot do that very same indexing to get members of the second hash. It is extremely frustrating because I see the data that I need in the print output, but cannot get that data and manipulate it (without going super jank and reading print output somehow... not a good way to do things). Any ideas on this?

Comment: Add the controller, to see what's `@uploaded_planners[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
params[:uploaded_planner][:pic].original_filename
```

Comment: in the print statement it appears to be a string, so maybe `["pic"]` instead.

Comment: Values of ActionController::Parameters are accessible both by symbol and string keys:

> You can fetch values of ActionController::Parameters using either :key or "key".
(http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html)